# How to minimize the maximum cost of a path in a vertex disjoint path cover?

Tags: graph-algorithm

Given a directed weighted graph G and n, where n is the number of paths to be used to cover all the vertices in the graph G. How can I minimize the maximum cost of the longest path? (assuming that a solution always exist in this graph)

Answer (score 0):

For n = 1, this obviously becomes a Travelling Salesman Problem - which is NP-hard. Thus, I wouldn't look for exact algorithms in your case.

My guess would be that a good solution for small n would be to use one of the abundant algorithms for the Travelling Salesman Problem (which usually approximate optimal solutions quite good) and then remove the (n-1) heaviest edges from the found path. That way you end with n paths.

[The Wikipedia Article on TSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Heuristic_and_approximation_algorithms) actually lists some pretty easy algorithmic techniques which should give you a reasonably good approximation.